# Smile Detection in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I have to do smile detection in Matlab and I am stuck on filtration of corners of lips. For this I am using following approach.

```
img = imread('smile.jpg');

faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Mouth','MergeThreshold',160);
cornerDetector = vision.CornerDetector('Method','Harris corner detection (Harris & Stephens)');
Irgb2gray=rgb2gray(img);

bboxes = step(faceDetector, Irgb2gray);
lips = imcrop(Irgb2gray,bboxes);

C = corner(lips);
imshow(lips);
hold on;
plot(C(:,1), C(:,2), 'r*');
```

I am getting corners of an image as:

[image]

I want to apply some filters so that I can get rid of some corners that are outside of Lips. I am stuck on this point how would I came to know which are good corners and those which are not good?
Then after correcting the corners I would have to calculate the distance between them so that I can tell if there was a smiley or not.

Can anyone please help me in **filtration of corners**? I would be thankful to you.

Comment: fed smailing faces and non similing to a neural network and start training

Comment: Hammad: If you want to manually find smile then finding corners is good option - You may find Mean Square distance between Corners returned. and choose the one pair with max distance between them

Comment: Also try : if you could draw lines between pixels which are farthest it should solve the problem as it will most probably be the line almost in between the lips.

Comment: Is the mouth always close? Then here's a completely other approach:
1. segment the lips
2. skeletonize
3. get the curvature of the remaining skeleton

Comment: @MattSchmatt No, it is not necessary that mouth is always close.

Comment: @dynamic Can neural network give results in real time if we run it on live stream?

Comment: depending on power maybe yes

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would train a smile vs. non-smile classifier. You could use the `extractHOGFeatures` or `extractLBPFeatures` function in the Computer Vision System toolbox to extract the features, and then use the `fitcsvm` function in the Statistics and Machine Learning toolbox to train the classifier. Of course, you would also have to collect images of smiles and non-smiles, and use `imresize` to make them the same size.